# PHP exception naming and error codes best practices?

Tags: php, error-handling, naming-conventions

What's your piece of advice on exception naming these days ?

- Standard (Java-style, old?) convention would be to keep them at the root of your namespace with an Exception suffix: `Example\Project\ConfigurationException`
- Symfony splits them by purpose/components ([source](http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Exception.html)):

  - `Example\Project\User\BannedUserException`
  - `Example\Project\Graphs\NotEnoughDataException`
- Facebook store them and keep the Exception suffix to its classes: `Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException.php` ([source](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4/blob/master/src/Facebook/Exceptions/FacebookSDKException.php))
- Braintree keep all its exceptions together inside an Exception folder: `Braintree\Exception\NotFound` ([source](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_php/blob/master/lib/Braintree/Exception/NotFound.php))
- Stripe has ditched entirely the word Exception in his SDK and keep them together inside the same folder: `Stripe\Error\InvalidRequest`. ([source](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/blob/master/lib/Error/InvalidRequest.php))

There seems to be as much as ways as there's developers out there... but is there a written convention or what's the trend out there used by the most of us ?

---

Also, do you always set an error code as part of your exceptions ? If so, how do you manage those code ?

I've got a bunch of constants in `Example\Project\Errors`, just like [Braintree does](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_php/blob/master/lib/Braintree/Error/Codes.php).

Comment: This question is as relevant today as the day it was asked.